# How to set a big size image background in Android Studio

Tags: android, uiimageview

I have a big size image, I copied and pasted into `Drawable`.

When I showed it, my app was crashed because of **`out of memory Exception`**.

Comment: Gimme error log..............Thanks !!!

Comment: how much big is big? log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your image from drawable folder to :
drawable-xxhdpi or xxxhdpi. It will work then

or

You can compress and resize the image to avoid out of memory error.

Comment: I use Image Asset to import image in Android Studio 3.2 . It created more image with <image_name>.png (hdpi) / (mdi) / (xhdpi) instead of drawable-xxhdpi or xxxhdpi folder. It auto choose low resolution image.

Comment: Yea it does it automatically. To save memory I guess.